# insertRowBefore the last Row returning error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that (gross, I know) writes to a spreadsheet. It dynamically adds and deletes rows based on input data from another sheet. I like doing this because the user has to copy and paste the resulting data, formatted into a table, into an email after (Let's skip creating an email directly from this script for now, that's part two).

I figured the easiest way to let the script know where to paste new data is to always insert a row before the very last row of the spreadsheet and paste said data.

I have been using getMaxRows(), getLastRow(), and insertRowBefore(), but all combos of these functions returns an "those rows are out of bounds" error! 
I really don't understand what's going on. I use logs and see the variables getLastRow() and getMaxRows both get updated after I've done some copying of a template table to the sheet which then "inserts" rows. For some reason, even after re-calling the getMaxRows() and getLastRow() functions, they don't recognize the new rows. The script can still manipulate these new rows.

This leads me to believe getMaxRows() and getLastRow() can only get info about the number of rows in the sheet only when the script first runs, or only when the sheet is first activated? Has anyone faced this issue before? Does anyone have details about how those two functions work? The GAS 'sheet' class page didn't help.

```
spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
emailsSheet = spread.getSheetByName("emails");
emailsMaxRows = emailsSheet.getMaxRows(); //# of rows regardless of content.
emailsSheet.deleteRows(2,emailsMaxRows-1); //I want to start from scratch each time I run the script, having just 1 row from which I append 'template' boxes where I can put data for the user to copy and paste into emails.
emailsMaxRows = emailsSheet.getMaxRows(); //now that I've deleted, Logger.log() shows that getMaxRows() correctly updates with just 1 row.
emailsSheet.insertRowsBefore(emailsMaxRows, 2);//insert two more, so there are 3 rows in the sheet.
emailsMaxRows = emailsSheet.getMaxRows(); //logger correctly shows 3
templateEmail = spread.getRangeByName("templateEmail"); //email template, A1:E5
templateEmail.copyTo(emailsSheet.getRange(emailsMaxRows,1)); //paste a table of 5 rows to row 3, so there are 7 total.
emailsMaxRows = emailsSheet.getMaxRows(); //should be 7, no?
//NO. Logger shows MaxRow is still 3, how come????? I can visibly see in the sheet there are 7 rows, with formatting and text. I simply don't understand how getMaxRows() doesn't update to return 7.
```

I need either getMaxRows() or getLastRow() to correctly update each time I delete or insert a row, why can't they do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpreadsheetApp.flush() fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution. This will hopefully help someone with the same issue.

Comment: You're welcome. As far as I can tell, unfortunately SpreadsheetApp.flush() will be required after each and every write/delete function made on the spreadsheet, to really ensure the action updates all the other functions (like getMaxRows()). This will greatly lengthen the execution time of scripts that make many modifications (hundreds, thousands, etc etc).